# Index.html is opening but the title and body is not coming up

Tags: html, browser

My `index.html` page is coming up, but it's totally blank. No matter what I write in the file, nothing is coming in the browser.

Please help me to troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: Is the file saved?

Comment: What have you tried? What technologies are you using? Where's your [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? This question is unanswerable because there is almost no information given on what the actual problem is.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.